# Java Generics and incremental compilation

Tags: java, javac

I've following classes which use generic types.

```
public class A<T> { }

public class B<T extends Number> { }

public class C {
    public A<B<?>> test() { return null;}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        A<B<? extends Number>> val = c.test();
    }
}
```

I'm able to compile all classes together using "javac A.java B.java C.java Main.java" (OpenJDK 11.0.8). After this, if I try to only recompile Main.java (with class files for other classes available in the current directory), javac complains about incompatible types.

```
 javac Main.java
 Main.java:4: error: incompatible types: A<B<?>> cannot be converted to A<B<? extends Number>>
            A<B<? extends Number>> val = c.test();
                                               ^
 1 error
```

I understand that I can get this working by changing the type of val variable to A<B<?>>. But I don't understand why recompiling Main.java independently fails and compiling it with other source files succeeds. Can someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: how you exactly do "compiling it with other source files" ?

Comment: javac A.java B.java C.java Main.java

Comment: I suppose then you run compile Main.java individually again after the .class has been created?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. "javac A.java B.java C.java Main.java"
completes successfully and generates .class files for all classes. After this, running "javac Main.java" fails with the error mentioned in the question above.

Comment: You might want delete the no longer required comments.